# Owner of uploads directory is `www-data` but this prevents FTP access via PHP scripts

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, permissions, ftp

To allow write access to Apache, I needed to `chown www-data:www-data /var/www/mysite/uploads` to my site's upload folder. This allows me to delete files from the folder via `unlink()` in a PHP script.

Unfortunately, this prevents another PHP script, which uses FTP functions, from working. I think it is because the FTP user is `mike` and now that the uploads directory is owned by `www-data`, `mike` cannot access it.

I added `mike` to the group `www-data`, but this does not fix the issue.

Can somebody advise me on how to allow PHP FTP functions to work in addition to file deletion using PHP's `unlink()` function?

Comment: what's the group permissions on /var/www/mysite/uploads set to?

Comment: @Zypher: Group permissions for `/var/www/mysite/uploads` are `r-s`

Comment: @letseatfood and in `/var/www/mysite`?

Comment: @jneves Group permissions for `/var/www/mysite` are `r-s`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That would be why, you need the 'write' permission to delete files. You have a couple of options here.

1. chwon /var/www/mysite/uploads to www-data:mike and chmod to 775 (rwxrwxr-x)
2. Create an ftp-write group and chown /var/www/mysite/uploads to www-data:ftp-write and chmod to 775
3. just chmod to 775 (rwxrwxr-x) and leave mike as part of the www-data group
4. set an acl on the folder for mike with `setfacl -m user:mike:rwx`
5. Create an ftp-write group, add mike and the group (as well as any other users that need these permissions with `setfacl -m group:<ftp_group>:rwx`

Comment: #3 worked (`chmod 775 /var/www/mysite/uploads` and leaving `mike` in the group `www-data`). Is this an okay solution?

Comment: @letseatfood: yep perfectly acceptable :) I listed them in no particular order.

Answer (score 0):

Filesystem permissions should be enough to fix your problem there.  Try something like chmod o+rw on the uploads directory ONLY.  The chmod command effectively says "give anyone that's not in the www-data group read and write permissions."

The longterm fix, though, would be to use a service account for your script that calls FTP, and to bundle that particular service account with www-data.

Comment: You don't want to be giving the "other" set o permissions more rights than you need to, chmod'ing the group is sufficient and opens less security risks.

Comment: Would you elaborate about the longterm fix that you mentioned?

Comment: Oh, do you mean that I should create a user specifically for FTP that is in the group www-data?

Comment: yes, that is the correct way to do so